# Can mobile device work optimumally well as canvas control does on desktop browser

Tags: html, image, mobile, canvas

I read an article saying it is best to use img control on mobile rather than use the canvas control.

Is this true as i cannot tell any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to test on your own device with your own code.

In general canvas is programmatically intensive and therefore will be slower on devices (like mobile) that are less-powerful.

In addition, desktop devices always (almost always) have a GPU which the native canvas element will use to speed its calculations and display.

In my own experience, computationally intensive canvas apps are slower (often much slower) on mobile than desktop.

If your design allows you to use a static image instead of a canvas on mobile, then use the static image.